# Unity2D character glitches through box collider instead of stopping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

I'm making a small game in Unity and I'm not very experienced in it yet. I am trying to fix a bug in movement, where instead of stopping when it runs into a 2D box collider, it still makes the character through the box collider, and it just gets forced into the wall. I've tried looking this up on google and StackOverflow, but I can't find the same problem I'm facing. Any help would be appreciated!

Movement script:

```cs
public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;

    public SpriteRenderer playerSpriteRenderer;

    public Animator animator;

    public bool isGrounded = false;

    public static Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D;
    void Awake()
    {
        rigidbody2D = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        
        Jump();
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f);
        transform.position += movement * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add collider properties for both player and wall? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i already had a box collider on both, it still doesn't work unfortunately :[ thanks though! :]

Comment: It is already clear you have collider in your both object. I just said **properties** because if you check **IsTrigger** checkbox in the wall box collider, all objects can pass through it.

Comment: oh, sorry for the misunderstanding haha! no, they don't have isTrigger checked.
[player inspector](https://gyazo.com/cf7a51c2f8c2724f0b0cbefa289eaaf0)
[wall inspector](https://gyazo.com/072a166d9fa5b500da19ea8da2cf9778)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make it collide try using `rigidbody.velocity`. `transform.position` is for non-collider objects.

So, your code should be:

```cs
rigidbody2D.velocity = movement * moveSpeed;
```

Comment: thanks, but now the player isn't moving at all

Comment: can you gimme the code to clarify the solution? I guessing that you put the rigidbody.velocity in time.deltaTime cause extremely slow movement.